# Python Pandas DataFrame to return all sets of dates within one month range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like the one below as an input:

[image]

Which was produced by the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = ['3-Apr-2018', '4-Apr-2018', '15-Apr-2018', '5-May-2018', '3-Jun-2018']
prices = [300, 200, 100, 900, 200]
list_of_tuples = list(zip(dates, prices))
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns=['dates', 'prices'])
```

I need all sets of date indexes that fall into a one month range or 31 days.  The output of this should be:

```
 [0, 1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]
```

Comment: Please copy/paste your toy data here. Do not include the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution … added a few extra steps just to make it easier to follow.

1. Always make sure to convert strings to dates
2. Add a start_date column
3. Add an end_date column
4. Write a for-loop that loops through each start_date and end_date, check entire column
5. Store the results in a temporary list that gets appended to a master list of results
6. Add the results master list to a new column

```py
# Step 1: make sure to convert the dates
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

# Step 2: create start_date
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

# Step 3: create end_date column that projects date forward 31 days
df['end_date'] = df['dates'] + pd.Timedelta(days=31)

# create master list to store results of search
list_column_index = []

# loop through each row in dataframe, start_date and end_date
for each_start, each_end in zip(df['start_date'], df['end_date']):

    # compare the entire 'dates' column to the start_date and end_date in this row
    mask_range = df['dates'].between(each_start, each_end)

    # create a new temporary dataframe with dates in this range
    temp_df = df.loc[mask_range]

    # convert the index of the temporary dataframe into a temp_list
    temp_list_index = list(temp_df.index)

    # add the temp list to the master list
    list_column_index.append(temp_list_index)

# add a new column with the master list
df['column_index'] = list_column_index

print(df)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For sure there is more optimal solution, but here is my proposal:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['3-Apr-2018', '4-Apr-2018', '15-Apr-2018', '5-May-2018', '3-Jun-2018']
prices = [300, 200, 100, 900, 200]
list_of_tuples = list(zip(dates, prices))
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns=['dates', 'prices'])

#solution:
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

for index, r in df.iterrows():
    df['c_' + str(index)] =  (df['dates'] - r['dates']).apply(lambda x: 1 if pd.Timedelta(0, unit='d')< x <pd.Timedelta(32, unit='d') else 0)
df['m'] = df.groupby(df['dates'].dt.month).ngroup()

d31 = [df.index[df[col] == 1].tolist() for col in df if col.startswith('c_') and df[col].sum() > 1]
months = [*(df.groupby(df['dates'].dt.month).groups.values())]
months = [m.to_list() for m in months]

d31_months = d31 + months
```

Output slightly different than yours, but I don't unstertand why don't include `[3], [4]` for months:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [3], [4]]
```

I've managed to refactor it a bit:

```
months = [list(m) for m in df.groupby(df['dates'].dt.month).indices.values()]

diff = lambda r: (df['dates'] - r['dates']).apply(lambda x: 1 if pd.Timedelta(0, unit='d') < x < pd.Timedelta(32, unit='d') else 0)
d31 = [list(np.nonzero(df.index[diff(r)])[0]) for i, r in df.iterrows() if diff(r).sum() > 1]

d31_months = d31 + months
```

Comment: your solution returns unexpected output. [0], [1, 2, 3, 4] and
[0,1,2], [3], [4]

Comment: Solution updated. I've looked at textual description.

Comment: i need to find prices exceeding certain amount in one month range